# Spark streaming jobs fail when chained

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm running a few a few Spark Streaming jobs in a chain (one looking for input in the output folder of the previous one) on a Hadoop cluster, using HDFS, running in Yarn-cluster mode.

```
job 1 --> reads from folder A outputs to folder A'
job 2 --> reads from folder A'outputs to folder B
job 3 --> reads from folder B outputs to folder C
...
```

When running the jobs independently they work just fine.

But when they are all waiting for input and I place a file in folder A, job1 will change its status from running to accepting to failed.

I can not reproduce this error when using the local FS, only when running it on a cluster (using HDFS)

```
Client: Application report for application_1422006251277_0123 (state: FAILED)
     INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1422006251277_0123 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1422006251277_0123_000002 exited with  exitCode: 15 due to: Exception from container-launch.
     Container id: container_1422006251277_0123_02_000001
   Exit code: 15
```

Comment: Can you just run job1 on the cluster, commenting out 2 and 3 for now ? does that work?

Comment: Yes, The jobs run individually on the cluster.

Comment: would it be because of starvation, i.e. job 2-4 also try to consume job1's input ? perhaps some code would shed some light ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Mapreduce ignores files that start with . or _, Spark Streaming does not.

The problem is, when a file is being copied or processes or whatever and there is a trace of a file found on HDFS(i.e. "somefilethatsuploading.txt.tmp") Spark will try to process it.

By the time the process starts to read the file, it's either gone or not complete yet.

That's why the processes kept blowing up.

Ignoring files that start with . or _ or end with .tmp fixes this issue.

**Addition:**
We kept having issues with the chained jobs. It appears that as soon as Spark notices a file (even if it's not completely written) it will try to process it, ignoring all additional data. The file rename operation is typically ***atomic*** and should prevent issues.